# How to tell MATLAB to open and save specific files in the same directory

Tags: matlab

I have to run an image processing algorithm on numerous images in a directory.

An image is saved as `name_typeX.tif`, so there are X different type of images for a given name.

The image processing algorithm takes an input image and outputs an image result.

I need to save this result as `name_typeX_number.tif`, where `number` is also an output from the algorithm  for a given image.

Now..

How do I tell MATLAB to open a specific `typeX` file? Also note that there are other non-tif files in the same directory.

How to save the result as `name_typeX_number.tif`?

The results have to be saved in the same directory where the input images are present. How do I tell MATLAB NOT to treat the results that have been saved as an input images?

I have to run this as background code on a server... so no user inputs allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are wanting to get all files in a directory whose names match a certain format, then process them all automatically. You can do this using the function [DIR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/dir.html) to get a list of file names in the current directory, then using the function [REGEXP](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/regexpi.html) to find file names that match a certain pattern. Here's an example:

```
fileData = dir();             %# Get a structure of data for the files in the
                              %#   current directory
fileNames = {fileData.name};  %# Put the file names in a cell array
index = regexp(fileNames,...                 %# Match a file name if it begins
               '^[A-Za-z]+_type\d+\.tif$');  %#   with at least one letter,
                                             %#   followed by `_type`, followed
                                             %#   by at least one number, and
                                             %#   ending with '.tif'
inFiles = fileNames(~cellfun(@isempty,index));  %# Get the names of the matching
                                                %#   files in a cell array
```

Once you have a cell array of files in `inFiles` that matches the naming pattern you want, you can simply loop over the files and perform your processing. For example, your code might look like this:

```
nFiles = numel(inFiles);    %# Get the number of input files
for iFile = 1:nFiles        %# Loop over the input files
  inFile = inFiles{iFile};  %# Get the current input file
  inImg = imread(inFile);   %# Load the image data
  [outImg,someNumber] = process_your_image(inImg);  %# Process the image data
  outFile = [strtok(inFile,'.') ...   %# Remove the '.tif' from the input file,
             '_' ...                  %#   append an underscore,
             num2str(someNumber) ...  %#   append the number as a string, and
             '.tif'];                 %#   add the `.tif` again
  imwrite(outImg,outFile);  %# Write the new image data to a file
end
```

The above example uses the functions [NUMEL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/numel.html), [STRTOK](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/strtok.html), [NUM2STR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/num2str.html), [IMREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/imread.html), and [IMWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/imwrite.html).

Comment: Thanks gnovice! On line 3
index = regexp(fileNames,'[A-Za-z]+_type\d+\.tif');

what if I want the number to be 1, 2 and 5 ( instead of all the other numbers available). 

I haven't ran the your code yet.. busy googling all the functions you've used :P  but is the "+" part of the code?

Comment: @its-me: If you want to match *only one* of the numbers 1, 2, or 5 after the word `type`, you can remove the `\d+` and replace it with `[125]`. The `+` is a quantifier indicating that the preceding character(s) be matched 1 or more times. I also added some extra links for the function documentation to my answer.