# Save mat file from MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to save variables in a loop with different image names, like

```
for i = 1:length(imagefile)
    name = imagefile{i};
    var = rand(100); % Just for example
    save name var
end
```

It will save `var` as `name`, but how do I save it with a value of name, for example `Canon101`?

Comment: Explain your question more. What exactly you'r trying to do ?

Comment: By the way **var** is a Matlab function, so its wise not to assign it as a variable name.

Comment: You may want to have a look at the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048453/how-to-tell-matlab-to-open-and-save-specific-files-in-the-same-directory)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sayyad, you don't have to use `eval`. You can simply use the function form of `save`, i.e., `save(filename,variables)`. This will use the value of `filename`. Remember that the variables need to be entered as strings. So, in your example, it would be

```
save(name,'var')
```