# Saving a file in MATLAB with a variable filename in a loop

Tags: matlab, variables, loops, filenames

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Save mat file from MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444483/save-mat-matlab)
>   [How to tell MATLAB to open and save specific files in the same directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048453/how-to-tell-matlab-to-open-and-save-specific-files-in-the-same-directory)

I have a set of [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) files and need to extract data to obtain plots. I use the following code to generate a variable file name in a loop and accordingly get the desired data.

```
P = dir('*.csv');

for m = 1:length(P)
    P(m).data = csvread(P(m).name);
end
```

I now want to modify these CSV files (change the data values in the CSV files) before obtaining the desired data and then save these files to Excel format (.xls) within the loop.

Something like

```
for i = 1:length(P(m).data)
    if P(m).data(i,1)< value1
        P(m).data(i,2) = 0;
    end
    save P(m).xls P(m).data -ascii; % Gives error "save 'P(m).data' is not a valid variable name."
end
```

How do I save a file in Excel (.xls) format with a variable filename obtaining data from array in a loop?

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048453/how-to-tell-matlab-to-open-and-save-specific-files-in-the-same-directory

Answer (score 2):

Check out the MATLAB documentation for the [`save()` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/save.html)

You need to use the function-call syntax to use variable file names:

```
save(P(m).xls, P(m).data, '-ascii');
```

**Edit**: you seem to have new errors.  I can see two things:

1. your `P` variable is a struct *array*, so it has more than 1 element -- `save()` can save only one file at a time;
   2 `xls` is not a file of your struct, which has a `name` field.

To save your data, it will probably resemble this:

```
for m = 1 : length(P),
    save(P(m).name, P(m).data, '-ascii');
end
```

If you want to replace the extension to avoid overwriting your files (I assume `xls` is what you wanted), this should do the trick:

```
for m = 1 : length(P),
    name = P(m).name;
    name = name(1:find(name,'.'));
    name = [name '.xls'];
    save(name, P(m).data, '-ascii');
end
```

Comment: I tried with the above syntax, but it's showing an error: Reference to non-existent field 'xls'.

Comment: @Parijat: updated my post, attempting to solve other errors.

Comment: Thanks Andre for your help. But I am afraid to say it's giving an error "Error using ==> save Argument must contain a string.
save(name, P(m).data, '-ascii');" I guess save doesn't accept a variable filename or variable data in a loop. Even the csv/xlswrite gives the error.